# Как заменить иконку кнопки после нажатия на неё?

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка `light`, нужно чтобы после того как нажать и отпустить её, иконка кнопки заменялась другой иконкой, а при последующем нажатии на неё, иконка заменялась обратно на предыдущую. Имею следующий код, но в нём иконка кнопки изменяется только при удержании. Но после того как отпускаеш кнопку, её иконка заменяется на первоначальную.
`Main.xml`

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/light"
    android:background="@drawable/states_light" />
```

Пытался сделать через `selector`.
`States_light.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/light_on" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/light_off" />
</selector>
```

Comment: попробуйте `myButton.setPressed(true)`

Comment: Тут больше подойдет что-нибуть вроде radiobutton

Comment: В Вашем случае используйте ToggleButton

Comment: `RadioButton`, или `CheckBox`

Comment: Проблема в том, что изображение (мои картинки которые я добавил вместо стандартного отображения кнопок), изменяется только при удерживании кнопки, а когда её отпускаешь, то кнопка меняется на первоначальную. А нужно чтобы после того как нажать и отпустить её, иконка кнопки заменялась другой иконкой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
boolean btnColor = true;
```

...

```
        light.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                light.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(btnColor){light.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); btnColor = false;}
                else {light.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); btnColor = true;}
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

В вашем случае, просто подготовьте нужные изображения к примеру в папку drawable и используйте их при изменении состоянии. К примеру:

```
    boolean btnColor = true;
```

...

```
        light.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                light.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_on);
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(btnColor){light.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_off_1); btnColor = false;}
                else {light.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_off_2); btnColor = true;}
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: А как это использовать не с цветом кнопки, а с её `background`?
  `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                light.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(btnColor){light.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); btnColor = false;}
                else {light.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); btnColor = true;}
            }`

Comment: всё очень просто, сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: `if(btnColor){light.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); btnColor = false;}`  
А в этом участке вместо `btncolor` нужно писать `background`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать методы setTag() и getTag() для Вашей кнопки и при нажатии проверять ее текущий тэг и менять background кнопки соответственно тэгу